# Kafka - uncompacted topics Vs compacted topics

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I come across the following two phrases from the book "Mastering Kafka Streams and ksqlDB" and author used two terms, what does they really mean "compacted topics" and "uncompacted topics"

Does they got anything to with respect to "log compaction" ?

> Tables can be thought of as updates to a database. In this view of the logs, only the current state (either the latest record for a given key or some kind of aggregation) for each key is retained. Tables are usually built from **compacted topics**.

> Streams can be thought of as inserts in database parlance. Each distinct record remains in this view of the log. Streams are usually built from **uncompacted topics**.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `log compaction` according to kafka docs

> Log compaction ensures that Kafka will always retain at least the last known value for each message key within the log of data for a single topic partition

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction

If log compaction is enabled on topic, Kafka removes any old records when there is a newer version of it with the same key in the partition log.

For more detailed explanation of log compaction refer - https://medium.com/swlh/introduction-to-topic-log-compaction-in-apache-kafka-3e4d4afd2262

Comment: thanks . one follow up question - without giving explicit hints about the topic being either compacted or uncompacted , does the "streams" takes care of streaming it accordingly meaning uncompacted events to KStream / compacted events to KTable ?

Answer (score 4):

From [this article](https://medium.com/swlh/introduction-to-topic-log-compaction-in-apache-kafka-3e4d4afd2262):

The idea behind compacted topics is that no duplicate keys exist. Only the most recent value for a message key is maintained.

> It is mostly used for the scenarios such as restoring to the previous state before the application crashed or system failed, or while reloading cache after application restarts.

As an example of the above kafka has the topic `__consumer_offsets` which can be used to to continue from the last message which was read after a crash or a restart. A schema registry is also often used to ensure compatible communication between producers and consumers. The schemas used are maintained in the `__schemas` topic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these terms are synonymous.

Ref: [Log Compaction](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction)

Comment: thanks. So, KTables will go with compacted topics and Kstreams go with uncompacted topics ? Do we need to tell this explicitly to "Streams" or streams takes care of it to stream it either compacted or uncompacted based on abstraction used either KStreams / KTables