# Kafka Streams - KStream with uncompacted topic

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Just followup question with respect to [Kafka - uncompacted topics Vs compacted topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63009907/kafka-uncompacted-topics-vs-compacted-topics/63010450#63010450)

As said there,

> Streams can be thought of as inserts in database parlance. Each distinct record remains in this view of the log. Streams are usually built from uncompacted topics.

As best practice, About the semantics of uncompacted topic , should the topic in question to be un compacted as in the log enabler should be disabled so that the compaction( cleaning ) will not happen, with property such as

> log.cleaner.enable = false  or log.cleaner.enable = true (default) with clean up policy as "delete"(default)

Answer (score 0):

Log Cleaner will not affect the performance of reading/writing from topics as they are a collection of background threads.

Therefore it is not necessary to disable log cleaning. Also, you may have some topics that use a delete policy and some topics that use a compact policy.

Please note that any state stores you create and use are backed by compacted topics.